# How to get the 7 days previous date of current date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working on a project where i need to set an alarm on 7 days before particular date the user has selected from date picker.

I used the following code to get the date from user

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePickerObj.date]];
[df release];
```

Can any one please tell me how to get the date of 7 days previous to the selected date.
Thanks in advance

Comment: All 7 days? Or 7 days before the selected date?

Comment: @ThomasW 7 Days before selected date

Answer (score 8):

Use `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`, like this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.day = -7;
NSDate *earlierDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components
    toDate:datePickerObj.date options:0];
```